# Proof of Eliminability Theorem in Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

I'm having trouble with a proof of the Eliminability Theorem in Set Theory given by the book "Basic Set Theory" by Azriel Levy.[image]

[image]

[image]

I have two questions:

I don't quite understand how they use the implicit proof by induction. Could someone explain this to me?

Also, why can we use induction here? This isn't spoken of at this stage and even if it were to be presented as an axiom, it relies on natural numbers. Isn't Set Theory supposed to define numbers their own way?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The induction happens in the meta-theory, not inside set theory. Yes, it might be surprising, but set theory needs a formal basis in order to be written down. This formal basis can be either set theory itself, or some weak theory of arithmetic.

Comment: Induction is in the meta-theory; meta-theory of course "knows" about simple structures linke strings and the ways to manage them : concatenating them, counting them.

Comment: Ok, that does make sense, but still, how is induction used here. What is the hypothesis?